# VBA: Range method failure

Tags: vba, excel

I was writing a code to select all the data entries of a Workbook which I 'Open' in a range, but the compiler gives error at the very last line (set up the Range rng)

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Range("C2") & Range("C3"))
'here Range("C2") & Range("C3") contains the location of the file's path
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
Dim frow As Long
frow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim rng As Range
Dim frow1 As Long
frow1 = ws.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set rng = wb.ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(frow, frow1))
```

Comment: `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Range("C2") & Range("C3"))` It is wrong. You specify the path of the workbook which you want to open instead of Range.

Comment: can you please post the values of Range C2 and C3?

Comment: It contains the file path, I've edited my question.

Comment: @kera_404 what is stored in "C2" and in "C3" , please post the strings you have for the file_path and file_name

Comment: Your syntax something like this: `Sub ImportWorksheet() 
    ' This macro will import a file into this workbook 
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select 
    PathName = Range("D3").Value 
    Filename = Range("D4").Value 
    TabName = Range("D5").Value 
    ControlFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name 
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=PathName & Filename 
    ActiveSheet.Name = TabName 
    Sheets(TabName).Copy After:=Workbooks(ControlFile).Sheets(1) 
    Windows(Filename).Activate 
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False 
    Windows(ControlFile).Activate 
End Sub `

Comment: In the last line, try replacing `Cells` by `ws.Cells`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Dim frow As Long
frow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim rng As Range
Dim fcol As Long
fcol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(frow, fcol))
```

Remember that if you are using a set worksheet u have to reference it in all range objects

Comment: I think we need `ws.` before `Cells(frow, frow1)`.